# ColdFusion adds unwanted output parameter to a stored procedure call

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, coldfusion

I am getting the following message from a stored procedure that does an update to a table:

`Procedure or function 'updateAttendee' expects parameter '@attendeeAutoID', which was not supplied.`

I actually know why I'm getting this error but I'm not sure I know how to fix what is causing it.

When I analyze the details and stack trace of the error, I can see that ColdFusion seems to be sending an extra parameter to the stored procedure. That parameter is an OUTPUT parameter. There are no output parameters listed in the parameter list in the stored procedure. This is the code for the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateAttendee] 

  @attendeeFName varchar(25)
, @attendeePreferredName varchar(25)
, @attendeeLName varchar(25)
, @attendeePhone varchar(25)
, @attendeeSecondaryPhone varchar(15) = NULL
, @attendeePrimaryEmail varchar(100)
, @attendeeSecondaryEmail varchar(100) = NULL
, @attendeeRank varchar(50)
, @attendeeTitle varchar(100)
, @attendeeOrganization varchar(100)
, @attendeeRequirements varchar(500) = NULL
, @attendeeCountryOfCitizenship varchar(50)
, @attendeeAutoID int
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE        dbo.conferenceAttendees
SET           attendeeFName = @attendeeFName
        , attendeePreferredName = @attendeePreferredName
        , attendeeLName = @attendeeLName
        , attendeePhone = @attendeePhone
        , attendeeSecondaryPhone = @attendeeSecondaryPhone
        , attendeePrimaryEmail = @attendeePrimaryEmail
        , attendeeSecondaryEmail = @attendeeSecondaryEmail
        , attendeeRank = @attendeeRank
        , attendeeTitle = @attendeeTitle
        , attendeeOrganization = @attendeeOrganization
        , attendeeRequirements = @attendeeRequirements
        , attendeeCountryOfCitizenship = @attendeeCountryOfCitizenship

WHERE       attendeeAutoID = @attendeeAutoID

END
```

The ColdFusion stored procedure call looks like this:

```
<cffunction name="updateAttendee" returntype="void" output="No">
<cfargument name="fieldValues" required="yes" type="struct" />
<cfstoredproc procedure="[dbo].[updateAttendee]" debug="yes" returncode="yes" datasource="#this.dsn#" username="#this.userName#" password="#this.password#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeFName"                   cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="25" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeFName#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeePreferredName"           cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="25" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeePreferredName#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeLName"                   cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="25" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeLName#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeePhone"                   cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="30" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeePhone#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeSecondaryPhone"          cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="30" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeSecondaryPhone#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeePrimaryEmail"            cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="100" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeePrimaryEmail#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeSecondaryEmail"          cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="100" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeSecondaryEmail#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeRank"                    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="50" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeRank#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeTitle"                   cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="100" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeTitle#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeOrganization"            cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="100" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeOrganization#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeRequirements"            cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="500" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeRequirements#">
    <cfif arguments.fieldValues.attendeeCountryOfCitizenship EQ "">
        <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeCountryOfCitizenship"    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="50" value="#arguments.fieldValues.otherCountryOfCitizenship#">
        <cfelse>
        <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeeCountryOfCitizenship"    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"      maxlength="50" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeCountryOfCitizenship#">
    </cfif>
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@attendeAutoID"                   cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"      maxlength="5" value="#arguments.fieldValues.attendeeAutoID#">

</cfstoredproc>
```

ColdFusion is making the SQL call like this:

```
{ (param 1) = call [dbo].[updateAttendee](@attendeeFName = (param 2) 
, @attendeePreferredName = (param 3) 
, @attendeeLName = (param 4) 
, @attendeePhone = (param 5) 
, @attendeeSecondaryPhone = (param 6) 
, @attendeePrimaryEmail = (param 7) 
, @attendeeSecondaryEmail = (param 8) 
, @attendeeRank = (param 9) 
, @attendeeTitle = (param 10) 
, @attendeeOrganization = (param 11) 
, @attendeeRequirements = (param 12) 
, @attendeeCountryOfCitizenship = (param 13) 
, @attendeAutoID = (param 14) )}
```

The parameters that are generated and sent to the stored procedure look like this:

```
 (param 1) = [type='OUT', sqltype='CF_SQL_INTEGER'] 
, (param 2) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='qwer', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 3) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='qwer', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 4) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='qwer', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 5) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='232-232-2323', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 6) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 7) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='qwer@ewr.klk', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 8) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 9) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='qwe', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 10) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='qwer', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 11) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='qwer', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 12) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='ghj', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 13) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='United States', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] 
, (param 14) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='685', sqltype='cf_sql_integer']
```

As you can see, Param 1 is generated as an OUTPUT parameter and is causing the parameter list to be out of sync.  I'm not asking for this parameter to be added. Something in CF seems to be doing it.  When i execute the stored procedure in a SQL window on the server it works perfectly.

My question is, How do I prevent CF from adding this extra parameter?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: That proc signature causes and error in CF11 & 2016 - *[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Procedure or function 'updateAttendee' expects parameter '@attendeeAutoID', which was not supplied.*". Works fine once you change the last param to `dbvarname="@attendeeAutoID"`.

Comment: Is it the returncode parameter that you have enabled in your attributes of the cfstoredproc call? This bit of code `returncode="yes"`.  Have you tried setting that to `no` and see if it removes the output parameter?

Comment: I am using CF2016 locally.  it will be CF2010 in production.  Setting the "returncode" attribute to "no" did not effect anything.

Comment: I take it back, setting the returncode attribute to "no" did remove the output parameter.  Now i just have to work at making sure they are all in the correct order.

Comment: Check the documentation of `cfprocparam` for your production version of ColdFusion.  Support for the `dbvarname` has changed over time you might be suffering a consequence of developing in a higher version.

Comment: @StuckInTheMud - Are you sure it's the same issue? Like I said, I got the same error due to a typo in the name of the last parameter `@attendeeAutoID`, but once fixed it worked fine. Granted I didn't trace the SQL, but the proc ran without error.  Also, what's the full version of 2016 you're using?

Comment: Thanks to all for your help.  In fact i saw the typo fixed it and that fixed the problem. But also, by changing the "returncode" attribute to "no" i was able to eliminate the unwanted output parameter.  It is running appropriately now.

Answer (score 1):

*Promoted from the comments*

The additional output parameter that you are seeing is due to the fact that you have included and enabled the `returncode` parameter of the `<cfstoredproc>` tag in this line of code.

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="[dbo].[updateAttendee]" debug="yes" returncode="yes" datasource="#this.dsn#" username="#this.userName#" password="#this.password#">
```

By adding `returncode="yes"` ColdFusion is requesting that additional output variable to capture the exit status of the stored procedure call.

From the [docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfstoredproc.html):

> returnCode - Optional
>
> Default value = no
>
> Description:
>
> - yes: populates `cfstoredproc.statusCode` with status code returned by the stored procedure.
> - no

So you can either remove that attribute from the `<cfstoredproc>` tag or set it to `no` or keep it as is and set a proper exit status within your stored procedure code.